# How to fix redefinition warnings from CSS Validator?

Tags: css, warnings, w3c-validation, redefinition

I just ran my site through the W3C CSS Validator
and it came out with a total of 3146 warnings.

Most of them are redefinition warnings like these:

```
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of color
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of color
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of font-size
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of font-size
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of background-color
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of background-color
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of display
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of display
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of height
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of height
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of line-height
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of line-height
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of width
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of width
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of text-align
.fa.fa-check    Redefinition of text-align
```

This is the script:

```
.fa.fa-check 
{
    color: #81D742;
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I can't figure out what to change for these warnings to disappear.

From what I've read, the redefinition warnings usually appear
when there is a duplicate definition in the style sheet,
but the only problem is that I can't find any duplicate definitions.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several instance of the .fa.fa-check in your website.
the css validator considerate you try to redefine the class.

Try to let only one instance of yout .fa.fa-check classes and it will solve the issue one this class.

Comment: The script that I posted above is the only occurrence of .fa-fa.-check in the entire html-document.

Comment: ok and do you import external stylesheet ? what i'm asking is if you redefine to time the class somewhere.

Comment: The only external stylesheet that I use is this one: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: i don't get warning about your code when i validate the css with the W3C validator by direct input. Which method do you used to validate you website ?

Comment: Then there must be something elsewhere in the html-document. I used validation by URI and the address http://www.esigaretten.no/.

Comment: yes your are right i saw the error now.
Why do you have several style tag in your page ?
It's not the reason but what i can advice you it's to externalise your css in a stylesheet document or have only one style tag.

Comment: I have no idea why they're cut up like this since I created the website with a web builder in the beginning. But now I can see that there actually are three different occurrences of .fa.fa-check in the different style-tags with different values for border-radius, height, line-height and and width.

Comment: yes that why you have the issue.
Like you have several instance of the .fa.fa-check the css validator considerate you try to redefine the class.

Comment: There must be a reason for the different values and I'll try to figure this out, but thank you so much for getting me this far.